# Armadillo BLAS Matrix Multiplication with it transpose. Blas is too slow?

Tags: c++, blas, armadillo

Does someone knows another trick or solution how can I perform matrix multiplication by its transpose?

The current code for 1000 iterations takes too much time for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

class watch : std::chrono::steady_clock {
    time_point start_ = now();
public: auto elapsed_sec() const {return std::chrono::duration<double>(now() - start_).count();}
};

template <typename T>
void matrix_multiplication(arma::Mat<T> const& input, arma::Mat<T> &output)
{
    const char N = 'N';
    const char C = 'C';
    std::complex<double> alpha {1.0};
    std::complex<double> beta  {0.0};
    int m_ = input.n_rows, n_ = input.n_rows, k_=input.n_cols;
    arma::blas::gemm(&N, &C, &m_, &n_, &k_, &alpha, input.memptr(), &m_, input.memptr(), &n_, &beta, output.memptr(), &n_);
}

int main()
{
    arma::cx_mat mat1; // size ( 300, 20'000)
    mat1.load("rec.txt"); // can be used arma::fill::randu
    arma::cx_mat resu(mat1.n_rows, mat1.n_rows, arma::fill::none);

    int N = 10;
    [&,_= watch{}](){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            matrix_multiplication(mat1, resu);
        }
        std::cout << _.elapsed_sec()/N <<std::endl;
    }();
    resu.submat(arma::span(0,1), arma::span(0,5)).print("resu");
        [&,_= watch{}](){
            for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                  resu = mat1 * mat1.t();
            }
            std::cout << _.elapsed_sec()/N <<std::endl;
        }();
            resu.submat(arma::span(0,1), arma::span(0,5)).print("resu");

    return 0;
}
```

My results :

```
0.0394106 << using armadillo blas wrapper.  
resu

0.0253328 << armadillo wrapper
resu
```

I am using for compilation part :

```
gcc 11.2
armadillo 10.7.3
opneblas
```

I tried to use syrk, but seems i am using something wrong :

Update :

```
template <typename T>
void matrix_zsyrk_multiplication(arma::Mat<T> const& input, arma::Mat<T> &output)
{
    std::complex<double> alpha {1.0};
    std::complex<double> beta  {0.0};
    int m_ = input.n_rows, k_ = input.n_cols;
    cblas_zsyrk(CBLAS_ORDER::CblasColMajor, CBLAS_UPLO::CblasUpper, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE::CblasNoTrans, blasint(m_), blasint(k_), &alpha, input.memptr(), blasint(m_), &beta, output.memptr(), blasint(m_));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Moreover, we all believe that whatever our computers do "take[s] too much time for me". Your question therefore only makes sense if you have a reason to believe that what you are trying to do could be done faster than what the code is currently doing. What's your evidence that this is so?

Answer (score 1):

`gemm` is the wrong routine: it does double the work, as it computes off-diagonal elements $C_{ij}=C_{ji}$ separately. You want to use `syrk` here.

Comment: I have tried to use : zsyrk, but i received the wrong values. Did i setup as excepted the configuration part ? 

My intention is to compute : 300 * 20'000 complex Mat with its transpose.

Comment: seems that i need to used 'herk'. Is possible to receive full nxn matrix, not only half of it , using 'herk' ?

Comment: Sorry, `herk` = Hermitian, $AA^H$. `syrk` = complex symmetric, $AA^T$ (no conjugates). I saw a `t` in your code and assumed you needed that. That may sound strange, but I don't know of a Lapack routine that copies "the other half" of the matrix into place. Maybe someone else can step in.

Comment: That's an operation you would usually avoid, but since gemm/herk is so much more expensive than a copy, I guess you could just do it with a for loop. Or if it's really large, dlacpy combined with an inplace transpose.

Comment: The matrix is aroung 300x20'000. The original one.